# Changing simple column of strings to date using to_datetime giving strange error

Tags: python

Trying to change date string to date in python. Fairly simple and not sure why not working. I realize I could consolidate the code a little but can someone point out why this is not working. Thanks.

```
 data_act1.ActionDate     data_act1.Action_Date_use
 20201112                 11/12/2020
 20200415                 04/15/2020
```

With dataframe like above, this code should work:

```
data_act1['month'] = data_act1['ActionDate'].str[4:6]
data_act1['day'] = data_act1['ActionDate'].str[6:]
data_act1['year'] = data_act1['ActionDate'].str[:4]

data_act1['Action_Date_use'] = data_act1['month']+"/"+data_act1['day']+"/"+data_act1['year']
data_act1.date_final = pd.to_datetime(data_act1.Action_Date_use, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Running this yields this error:

```
ValueError: time data '//' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

Update: Had instances of ActionDate being empty so that caused the error above. After removing those, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Tried

```
data_act1['date_final'] = pd.datetime(data_act1['Action_Date_use'].astype(str), format = '%m/%d/%Y')
```

and still getting same error.

Comment: Did you tried in two steps: 1- `data_act1['Action_Date_use'].astype(str)` and 2-`data_act1['date_final'] = pd.datetime(data_act1['Action_Date_use'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you dont have any cells with '//' :

```
print(data_act1[data_act1['Action_Date_use']=='//'])
```

If yes maybe do a replace:

```
data_act1['Action_Date_use'] =data_act1['Action_Date_use'].str.replace('//','01/01/1990')
```

Comment: Hey Renaud, can you look at my updated question. Got new problem after making the edit you suggested.